# Change listviews field property from main activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I am working on an Android application.In my main activity i have to implement a list.The following is the sample shape of my page

```
|----------------------| \
|  |Button|            |  \
|----------------------|   \                  
|listview row1         | \   \
|listview row1         |  \   \---------Screen
|listview row1         | / --/----- ListView 
|                      |/   /
|                      |  /
|                      | /
|______________________|/
```

The button is in my activity page and listview rows are creating in baseadapter.Listview is containing a textview.Now I have to change the Textviews background color when I click the button from activity and next time I click the button the textviews color will retain the old color.How can I do it friends?. I declared textview in getview() method.

Comment: Do you want change all textview background color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the solution.It may helpful to others.But I am not about the quality of my code.

step 1)

I craete variable in my activity

```
static int hidestate=0;
```

And in the hide buttons on click method I write this

```
hide_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (hidestate==0) {

                hidestate=1;

                sMSConversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hide_btn.setText("Show All");

            }else {
                hidestate=0;

                sMSConversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hide_btn.setText("Hide All");
            }

        }
    });
```

Step 2)
The following is my BaseAdapter class getView()

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    final TextView message;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smsconversation_row, null);

    RelativeLayout nws=(RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.all);
    message=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.snt_txt);

    if (SMSConversationHome.hidestate==1) {
        message.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    else{

        message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Thank you friends For yours help.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably other methods, but I'd cycle through the list rows in the OnClick method for the button. Something like:

In your activity field definitions:

```
    static final int colourA=Color.argb(255,255,0,0);
    static final int colourB=Color.argb(255,0,255,0);
    int currentColour=colourA;
```

In your activity OnCreate:

```
        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton); 
        final ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewByID(R.id.myListView);
        //change myButton to your button id, and myListView to your ListView id
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //This is the code to toggle the colours, you can do pretty much whatever you want here though
                if (currentColour==colourA){
                    currentColour=colourB;
                } else {
                    currentColour=colourA;
                }

                //This cycles through all the root views in the ListView. If you want to change the
                //colour of only one view in the row layout, in the for loop use 
                //rowView.findViewById(R.id.myViewInRow).setBackgroundColor(currentColour);
                //instead, to get the relevant view in the row
                View rowView;
                for (int i=0;i<myListView.getChildCount();i++){
                    rowView=myListView.getChildAt(i);
                    rowView.setBackgroundColor(currentColour);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @skyrift..I am using custom base adapter.

Comment: If all you want to do is to change the background colour of your rows, this should work regardless of the adapter being used - it's operating above that level, with the ListView itself. Though from the solution you posted below it looks like you wanted to hide a part of the layout, not change it's colour.